# Spectral density of fluctuations (white noise/delta-correlated process)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, noise, fluctuation-dissipation

Let I be the current flowing across some junction as a result of N charge carriers of charge q. And let $\langle I (t) \rangle$ be its average.

Assume a particle number distribution such that its fluctuation is given by $\langle (\Delta N)^2 \rangle=\langle N\rangle$.

So $\langle I\rangle = q \langle N \rangle$ and by definition of the correlation function $K_I(\tau)=\langle (\Delta I)^2 \rangle$
(where $\tau$ be the time difference $t' - t$) we have

$$
K_f(\tau)= q \langle I\rangle
$$

Simplifying this comes from the fact that the charge carriers flow randomly and independently. So we use the following:

Let the spectral density of fluctuations be defined as the Fourier transform of the correlation function $K_f(\tau)$

$$
S_I(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} K_f(\tau) e^{i \omega \tau} d\tau
$$

The random and independent nature of the system means that this is a delta-correlated process, where we have $S_f(\omega)= constant = S_f(0)$,

so that via an inverse fourier transform we have

\begin{eqnarray}
K_I(\tau) &=& 2\pi S_I(0) \delta(\tau) \\
&=& 2 \pi \bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} K_f(\tau) e^{i 0 \tau} d\tau \bigg) \delta(\tau) \\
&=& \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} K_f(\tau) d\tau  \delta(\tau) \\
&=& K_f(0) \delta(\tau) \\
\end{eqnarray}

I am trying to understand if this next step I take is legitimate:

Could I not rearrange the first line of the above equation to say

\begin{eqnarray}
K_I(\tau) &=& 2\pi S_I(0) \delta(\tau) \\
q \langle I\rangle &=& 2\pi S_I(0) \delta(\tau) \\
\frac{q \langle I\rangle}{2\pi \delta(\tau)} &=& S_I(0) 
\end{eqnarray}

I hope this is more clear now.

My motivation behind the original question

*if , for an average quantity $\langle I \rangle$, does*

$$
\frac{\langle I \rangle}{\delta(\tau)} = I
$$

*Would* $$S_I(\omega)=S_I(0)= \frac{q \langle I \rangle}{2  \pi \delta(\tau)}$$ *or* $$S_I(\omega)=S_I(0)= \frac{q \langle I \rangle}{\delta(\tau)}$$

is that I know the answer to be

$$
S_I = q I
$$

with no average $\langle I \rangle$ or $2\pi$.

Comment: usually it is bad enough to multiply with $\delta(\cdot)$ but dividing with it is utter nonsense

Comment: Also note that the units are not consistent in the equation $\langle I \rangle / \delta(\tau) = I$, since $\delta(\tau)$ has units of 1/time. I think we need a bit more detail on what you want to calculate.

Comment: How does $\delta(\tau)$ have units of time? I didn't know a distribution like the Dirac delta could have units @Andrew

Comment: $\int {\rm d} \tau \delta(\tau)=1$, and ${\rm d} \tau$ has units of time, so $\delta(\tau)$ must have units of 1/time. You can also see this from the scaling rule $\delta(a x)=1/a\delta(x)$.

Comment: @andrew I see! thank you. ok allow me to edit the question to be more detailed

Comment: @Andrew edited now

Comment: I am still having a hard time following. To me the notation is very unclear. Does $\langle \cdot \rangle$ refer to average over time? If so, why does $q \langle I \rangle$ depend on time? What is the difference between $K_f$ and $K_I$? Is $q$ the charge of a charge carrier, or the total charge carried through the junction in some period of time? I think it would help to rewrite the question, being very careful to define all notation.

Comment: Indeed! I is I(t). There are N charge carriers with q charge each. $K_f$ is a generic equation, the correlation of a quantity f(t), $K_I$ is with $f=I$.

Comment: Is $\delta$ a delta distribution or does it represent variation? Or perhaps you're using it in both ways?

Comment: @N.Steinle I changed all my variances to triangle deltas to be more clear.

Comment: When you integrate, the delta function automatically disappears.  That's how it works.  It is meant to be used in an integral to define the value of some function no matter what the integral (assuming the value is within the bounds of integration).  So I don't see how the delta function survived the integration of $K_{f}$.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I see your point! your comment amounts to $K_I(\tau) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} K_f(\tau) d\tau  \delta(\tau) = K_f(0) \delta(\tau)$ is incorrect and should be, $K_I(\tau) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} K_f(\tau) d\tau  \delta(\tau) = K_f(0)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @honeste_vivere thank you!

Comment: Just a note on notation: you should write $\int_{-\infty}^\infty K_f(\tau) \delta(\tau) d\tau$, not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty K_f(\tau) d\tau \delta(\tau)$. The $\delta(\tau)$ is part of the integrand. Also just out of curiosity, what is the difference between $K_I(\tau)$ and $K_f(\tau)$?

Comment: @honeste_vivere please feel free to write an answer for the bounty :)

Comment: The problem is that you use $\tau$ as an integration (dummy) variable, which has made you confused. You should have written $\int K(\tau') d\tau' \delta(\tau)$, which is **not** equal to $K(0)$ (nor of course $K(0)\delta(\tau)$).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your definition of the correlation function is incorrect, and much confusion follows from there. If $I(t)$ is a random process (i.e. a variable randomly changing in time), then we can define:

- *Average/mean*: $\langle I(t)\rangle$
- *Fluctuation* (which is also a random process, but with zero mean): $\Delta I(t) = I(t) - \langle I(t)\rangle$
- *Variance* : $Var(I(t)) = \langle (\Delta I(t))^2\rangle$
- *Correlation function*: $K(t,t_1)=\langle \Delta I(t)\Delta I(t_1)\rangle$

In many situations the random process can be argued to be *stationary*, i.e. its moments, such as mean and variance, do not depend on time, whereas the correlation function depends only on the difference of times:
$$
K(\tau) = \langle \Delta I(t+\tau)\Delta I(t)\rangle
$$
Obviously variance is the value of correlation function at equal times or, for a stationary process:
$$
Var(I) = K(0) = \langle(\Delta I)^2\rangle,
$$
which is what the first equation in the original question should have been.

Comment: Hi, the definition you give are what I use.

Comment: @LopeyTall You equate the variance with the correlation function: $K_I(\tau)=\langle(\Delta I)^2\rangle$. One is a constant, the other is a function of time.